# Add line (adding a related record)

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I'm showing a related model by using the

```
related_model_ids
```

field in the model form view

The link for adding a record in the related model is

"Add a line" (in the attached image it's "Aggiungi riga", that's the transaltion in Italian)
[image: a screenshot of the said string]

What's the idiomatic odooish way to change that string ?

Is it by overriding the `default_view_get` method ?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to achieve.

**Change the string for that one case**

You can add controls to your tree view and decide what strings will be used.
[Link to the official doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/17.0/developer/reference/user_interface/view_architecture.html#control-create-customize-add-a-line)

For example:

```xml
<tree>
  <control>
    <create string="Add a pizza"/>
    <create string="Add some pasta"
        context="{'default_type': 'pasta'}"/>
    <create string="Add some olive oil"
        context="{'default_type': 'oliveoil'}"/>
  </control>
  <field name="name"/>
  <field name="amount"/>
</tree>
```

**Change the string for all default cases**

Changing the default string can probably be made by overriding the translation "Add a line" (web module: #: code:addons/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_editable_renderer.js:0)
or by extending/changing that part on the list_renderer's JavaScript code which can be found [here for Odoo 14](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/5cd0df5c813aae3da9b82e3fa986269f2b38e71b/addons/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_editable_renderer.js#L83-L87).

**Edit for atleast Odoo 14**: Seems that the controls only work with extra widgets, for example the widget `section_and_note_one2many`. So you have to change the `field` node by adding the widget. Then you can use the controls.

Comment: Case 1 applies to 17.0 but it seems the same "control" tag seems to be not available in 14.0

Comment: You're right, atleast in Odoo 14.0 it can only be used in combination with a widget. I will add that info in my answer.